# Why does the unification not work ? Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to unify the following terms in Prolog.

```
m(2 * 3 + 4) = m(X * Y).
```

The reaction is "false".

Why?  Would X=2 and Y= 3+4 not work?

Comment: But `m(2 * 3 + 4) = m(X + Y)` does work!

Comment: True, but m(2 * 3 + 4) = m(X * Y) does not, and I dont know why.

Comment: The * is evaluated before + by BODMAS rule

Comment: Are you sure ? I thought Prolog does only care about lexicographic equality.

Comment: Say `write_canonical( m(2 * 3 + 4) = m(X * Y) )` to see how operators resolve.

Comment: I am getting the following result :  (m(+(*(2,3),4)),m(*(_,_))), this means even at unification the BODMAS rule does apply? Correct ? If so, why does the following unificate with success? : o(A*B+Y)=o(D+E). => D=A*B,Y=E.

Comment: Unification doesn't know nothing about operators. Only `read/1` and similar built-ins does and it uses all kinds of operators similar to other languages. After converting text to Prolog terms unification gets the terms as you see them without any operator info attached, just like `write_canonical/1` does.

Comment: It is parsed as `(2*3) + 4`, hence that does not unify with `X * Y`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operators take precedence into account: the `+` operator has a lower precedence than the `*` operator. This thus means that:

```
m(2 * 3 + 4)
```

is parsed as:

```
m((2 * 3) + 4)
```

or more canonical:

```
m(+(*(2,3),4))
```

But this does not follow the pattern:

```
m(*(X,Y))
```

hence unification fails.

You can unify this by adding brackets, like:

```
?- m(2 * (3+4)) = m(X * Y).
X = 2,
Y = 3+4.
```

Comment: Thx, I think I got it now.